# How to convert Java "Arrays.copyOfRange" function to C#?

Tags: c#, java, arrays

Working on MergeSort in Java:

```
public void mergeSort(int[] A)
{
     if (A.length > 1)
     {
         int q = A.length/2;
         int[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, q);
         int[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A,q,A.length);
         mergeSort(leftArray);
         mergeSort(rightArray);
         merge(A,leftArray,rightArray);
     }
}
```

The recursion in the code above works well in Java.

So for curiosity I want to convert function Arrays.copyOfRange from java to c#.
Array.copy in C# takes five arguments. Do you know any simpler function in c# do get certain elements of the array starting at position x to y (like java).

In c# I coded the above method like this:

```
public void mergeSort(int[] A)
{
    if (A.Length > 1)
    {
        int q = A.Length / 2;
        int[] leftArray = new int[q];
        int[] rightArray = new int[A.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        {
            leftArray[i] = A[i];
            Console.WriteLine(leftArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = q; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            rightArray[i] = A[i];
            Console.WriteLine(rightArray[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        mergeSort(leftArray);
        mergeSort(rightArray);
        merge(A, leftArray, rightArray);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have replaced Arrays.copyOfRange functions in Java with two loops in c# and this works in c# without recursion.
However calling mergeSort(leftArray) and mergeSort(rightArray) it prints this in c#:

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException!!

Any better idea on how to get certain elements in c#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? This is precisely the info I was looking for

Comment: I also am baffled by the downvotes. Perhaps the downvoters are not familiar enough with both java and C# to grasp that the java function `copyOfRange` has no direct equivalent in C#, in the sense that C# requires a separate action to create an array, before performing Array.Copy. This is why a newcomer to C# may struggle a bit before seeing a good equivalent. IMHO this question is very useful to some beginners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the ported array copy is *not* doing the same thing.

Given an input of `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` the Java code is creating two arrays, `[a,b,c]` and `[d,e,f]` while the C# port is creating two arrays, `[a,b,c]` and `[0,0,0,d,e,f]`. Notably,

- The new right array is the size of A (`new int[A.Length]`). This is what causes the StackOverflowException as the termination case is never reached, and;
- The new right array is only assigned values starting at the `q` index, which is the half-way index.

Consider this replacement method using [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - a method with the same signature can be used as a drop in replacement in ported code, as long as what's inside the method has the same effect as the original.

```cs
int[] copyOfRange (int[] src, int start, int end) {
    int len = end - start;
    int[] dest = new int[len];
    Array.Copy(src, start, dest, 0, len);
    return dest;
}
```

Or, a version that does it with a loop but without the issue in the original port. Another reason to use discreet functions - it makes the task easy to see  and reason about. Being able to also eliminate duplicate code doesn't hurt.

```cs
int[] copyOfRange (int[] src, int start, int end) {
    int len = end - start;
    int[] dest = new int[len];
    // note i is always from 0
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        dest[i] = src[start + i]; // so 0..n = 0+x..n+x
    }
    return dest;
}
```

If you're lazy like me, the code could also be trivially written using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).

```
int[] leftArray = A.Take(q).ToArray();
int[] rightArray = A.Skip(q).ToArray();
```

Comment: calling your first method: int[] copyOfRange (int[] src, int start, int len) with parameters: A, 0, q prints the following error: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Comment: @Milot25 That was my original version, but (due to an oversight) it didn't match the Arrays.copyOfRange contract - oops. I've updated the code in the post for both functions to take in an `end` parameter (from which `len` is derived) so that can *actually* be used as a drop-in replacement for Java's Arrays.copyOfRange.

Comment: Your function is working. However I think the recursive method is causing something wrong in C#. Given an array: int[] a = {6, 3, 8, 5, 1, 9, 7, 3, 2, 4}; it prints only 3,6 whereas in Java: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @Milot25 Maybe the `merge` method is wrong? The input array and the output array *must* be the same size - if not, then elements were lost. I am very suspicious of this reported result as the final output array *is* the same as the input array (and thus even if there are bunch of `0` elements, it should be the *same* length).

Comment: I realize I have made some semantic mistake in merge algorithm implementation. Now everything works fine. Thanks very very much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Now in modern C# there is a simple solution for this:

```cs
string[] cuttedArray = array[2..6] // from second element to sixth element exclusive
```